# Is there a way to jump straight to the magit-status page of another git project?

Tags: emacs, magit, emacs-projectile

My general workflow for going to another project is

1. `projectile-switch-project` which pops up a helm interface for picking a project
2. select a project
3. select a file within the project to open the file
4. then run `magit-status`

Is there a way to combine steps 2-4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. `projectile-switch-project` which pops up a helm interface for picking a project

If you want to use `projectile` with `helm`, you could give [`helm-projectile`](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile) a try.

1. `helm-projectile-switch-project`
2. then choose your project with <kbd>M-g</kbd> or <kbd>f3</kbd> instead of <kbd>RET</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I've updated my shortcut to go with `helm-projectile-switch-project` instead of the non-helm version, thanks! Would you know if there's a way to see what the other possible shortcuts are when scrolling through those project candidates?

Comment: You can see more actions in the action menu with `TAB` (the default Helm binding)

Comment: or `C-z` (if you swapped).

Comment: Follow up, would you know how I'd be able to remap `M-g` on that keymap to a different shortcut? I'm not sure how to get the keymap or the shortcut since it appears `C-h k` that I normally use is overridden by the keymap

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use many projectile features, you can take a look at the built-in `project`, whose `project-switch-project` will let you select a command after selecting the project like:
[image]

Or you may add actions to open magit status for the project to helm like https://occasionallycogent.com/emacs_custom_helm_actions/index.html (something similar [embark](https://github.com/oantolin/embark) in helm if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may be able to code a little function that does what you need and attach it to `projectile-after-switch-project-hook`. At least running `magit-status` on that hook (if it's a git project), should be pretty easy to do.

EDIT: Tried it out. It interferes with `projectile-switch-project-action`. Good news is that you can just use that instead.

Here's a draft:

```
(defun my-projectile-switch-project-action ()
  (interactive)
  ;; test for some typical files in my projects
  (ignore-errors
    (let ((files '("README" "README.md" "build.gradle")))
      (while files
        (message "Looking for: %s" (first files))
        (if (file-exists-p (first files))
            (progn
              (find-file-other-window (first files))
              (setq files nil))
          (setq files (rest files))))))
  ;; now run magit
  (if (vc-git-responsible-p default-directory)
      (magit-status)))


;; Use the function like this:
(setq projectile-switch-project-action
      #'my-projectile-switch-project-action)
```

I hereby put above code under the GPLv2 or later in addition to StackOverflow's standard license. You can chose under which license you want to receive this code.